# Don't know how to initialize BATTERY_STATUS structure in winapi C++

Tags: c++, winapi

Other battery structures are firstly instanciated and after that filled with the values by system call like 'GetSystemPowerStatus', but in the related section of microsoft documentation the way of initialization of BATTERY_STATUS structure isn't mentioned https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/blob/docs/desktop-src/Power/battery-status-str.md.
So, tell me please the way on how to initialize this structure.

I've searched a lot stackoverflow and microsoft documentation to find the answer but haven't found it. I also look for any way to find the battery voltage using the WINAPI.

Comment: You don't need to initialize it. The `DeviceIoControl` function fills it in. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/enumerating-battery-devices

Comment: You have an example here in C# https://gist.github.com/ahawker/9715872 it's doing full native interop so it should be easy to backport to C/C++

Comment: It's the same as *GetSystemPowerStatus*. Does the following answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The *BATTERY_STATUS* structure is as **output** buffer to return according to [IOCTL_BATTERY_QUERY_STATUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/ioctl-battery-query-status) control code.

For an example, see [Enumerating Battery Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/enumerating-battery-devices) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77688747/dont-know-how-to-initialize-battery-status-structure-in-winapi-c#comment136964917_77688747) supplied by @SimonMourier.